# tkz-euclide not working since update

Tags: tkz-euclide

Since last update `\usepackage{tkz-euclide}` latex compiles nothing, and produces the error:

> File `tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex' not found. \input{tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex}

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
... 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce the problem. What exactly did you update? What TeX installation are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it breaks in miktex, but the version (4.24c) there is a bit older as in texlive which 4.25c. The annoucement text of the new version said " Remove \input{tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex} from the list of
 files to load.  This file is now useless because you have to
 use \tkzDrawPolygon instead of \tkzDrawTriangle.".  So you probably will have to wait for the next update or install manually.

Comment: If I hide the line:

%\input{tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex} in tkz-euclide.sty
all the documents are working! 
tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex is in the directory and opens ...

Comment: I use version MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.11 (MiKTeX 22.8.28) under Ubuntu 22.04. The update I meant was tkz-euclide. What Ulrike Fischer said seems very likely, for now all my documents are running as before. So I wait for the new update. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As often Ulrike is right. Some simplifications took place in an intermediate version now `input{tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex}` is unnecessary. You have two solutions 1) install version 4.25 which can be found on ctan.org 2) look for the file `tkz-euclide.sty` and delete the line: `tkz-obj-eu-draw-triangles.tex`. I'm sorry I left this error.